# Some sizes of Tahoma font are rendered very badly

Tags: fonts, 23.10, subpixel-rendering

Some emails come to me in HTML format and they use the **Tahoma** font, so switching to another font is something that I cannot do. The Tahoma font is installed on my system. However, some sizes of this font are rendered very badly.

I have tested with the **Font Manager** and **LO Writer** and seen that:

---

1. Font sizes **10.0 and below** are badly rendered (with ***no*** "Subpixel Antialiasing" = SA) and some non-English characters being replaced with some different font (but ***with*** SA):

[image]

---

---

2. Font size **10.5** is rendered correctly (with SA):

[image]

---

---

3. Font sizes **11.0, 11.5, and 12.0** have the same problem as in 1:

[image]

---

---

4. Font sizes **12.5 and above** are OK again:

[image]

---

---

Why is this so for a "TrueType" font? What can I do to fix the problem in case 3 above? What is the correct way of installing the **Tahoma** font to an Ubuntu system?

Note: If it has any meaning: XOrg or Wayland behave the same.

Answer (score 1):

I had a look at the anti aliasing of the Tahoma font you use. I tried out the sizes 10, 10.5, 11, 12, and all in regular, bold, and italic. My tests were run under Ubuntu 23.10. I downloaded and installed the Tahoma fonts from [here](https://www.dafontfree.io/tahoma-font/). All tests passed through just fine. No errors whatsoever. Have a look at the screenshot:

[image]

I would recommend that you try and re-install the Tahoma fronts on your system and then try again. If the anti aliasing errors still remain, you could setup Ubuntu 23.10 in VirtualBox, install the Tahoma fonts there, and test if the errors remain.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Indeed, by the time you were writing your answer, I copied the font files **tahoma.ttf** and **tahomabd.ttf** from a Windows 11 machine (probably, something not very legal, but OK for testing) into my `~/.local/share/fonts` folder, and the problem was solved. The Tahoma font provided by Ubuntu is very old (version 0.001, year 2004, glyph count 988), while the one I copied from Windows is version 7.01 (year 2020, glyph count 4495).

Comment: I filed a bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wine/+bug/2046828